# SSIS Get Substring From Right

Tags: ssis

I am currently updating an already existing SSIS package.It pulls data from XML data source.
Currently in one column It is inserting like "987698761234"
What I want is that only the last 4 digits to be Inserted into DB.

What should be the value of expression in the Derived Column Transformation Editor?

Comment: Solved:I have to use RIGHT([Data Conversion].Col_name,4)  Problem was that I need to select Replace 'Data Conversion,Col_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start here :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141162.aspx
The following example uses a string literal. The return result is "Bike".
RIGHT("Mountain Bike", 4)